# netcat command option difference between ubuntu 20.04.01 and it compiled from source code

Tags: linux, netcat

netcat command that installed on Ubuntu 20.04.01 by default has -X option, but netcat 0.7.1 compiled from source code does not have -X option. What is the difference?

netcat that installed on Ubuntu 20.04.01:

```
foo@foo:~/data/tmp$ netcat --help
netcat: invalid option -- '-'
usage: nc [-46CDdFhklNnrStUuvZz] [-I length] [-i interval] [-M ttl]
          [-m minttl] [-O length] [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port]
          [-q seconds] [-s source] [-T keyword] [-V rtable] [-W recvlimit] [-w timeout]
          [-X proxy_protocol] [-x proxy_address[:port]]           [destination] [port]
```

netcat 0.7.1 compiled from the source code:

```
foo@foo:~/data/tmp$ ./netcat/bin/netcat --help
GNU netcat 0.7.1, a rewrite of the famous networking tool.
Basic usages:
connect to somewhere:  ./netcat/bin/netcat [options] hostname port [port] ...
listen for inbound:    ./netcat/bin/netcat -l -p port [options] [hostname] [port] ...
tunnel to somewhere:   ./netcat/bin/netcat -L hostname:port -p port [options]

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
Options:
  -c, --close                close connection on EOF from stdin
  -e, --exec=PROGRAM         program to exec after connect
  -g, --gateway=LIST         source-routing hop point[s], up to 8
  -G, --pointer=NUM          source-routing pointer: 4, 8, 12, ...
  -h, --help                 display this help and exit
  -i, --interval=SECS        delay interval for lines sent, ports scanned
  -l, --listen               listen mode, for inbound connects
  -L, --tunnel=ADDRESS:PORT  forward local port to remote address
  -n, --dont-resolve         numeric-only IP addresses, no DNS
  -o, --output=FILE          output hexdump traffic to FILE (implies -x)
  -p, --local-port=NUM       local port number
  -r, --randomize            randomize local and remote ports
  -s, --source=ADDRESS       local source address (ip or hostname)
  -t, --tcp                  TCP mode (default)
  -T, --telnet               answer using TELNET negotiation
  -u, --udp                  UDP mode
  -v, --verbose              verbose (use twice to be more verbose)
  -V, --version              output version information and exit
  -x, --hexdump              hexdump incoming and outgoing traffic
  -w, --wait=SECS            timeout for connects and final net reads
  -z, --zero                 zero-I/O mode (used for scanning)

Remote port number can also be specified as range.  Example: '1-1024'
```

Comment: The difference is that one has -X and one doesn't?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to use -X option but GNU netcat doesn't have -X option.

Answer (score 1):

The netcat from Ubuntu is Open BSD one :

```
$ netcat -help
OpenBSD netcat (Debian patchlevel 1.206-1ubuntu1)
```

And you compiled the GNU version:

```
$ ./netcat/bin/netcat --help
GNU netcat 0.7.1, a rewrite of the famous networking tool.
```

This [post](https://askubuntu.com/q/346869/1144515) discusses the differences between both.

Comment: I knew there are some derived netcat such as GNU, OpenBSD...

Comment: @K.Minoda: I updated the answer with a link to a post which gives details on the differences.

Comment: Thank you. I  understood the significant difference between traditional and openbsd.